# Continuous deployment for Classic ASP using VSO and Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, asp-classic, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

We have a set of Classic ASP websites that we are trying to integrate with VSO and Continous Deployment to Azure Web Sites.

Here are some details:

- Our Solution is made up of Classic ASP Web Sites
- We use TFS in VSO
- When changes are checked in, we would like the changed files to be deployed to our Azure Web Site.  Not all the files, as there could be hundreds or thousands of objects.  Just the changed objects.

I've been scouring the web for help on this, but have come up short in two key areas:

1. How do I get just the changed files?
2. How do I deploy those changed files?

We use a similar (but much clunkier) process in our on-premises using a combination of SourceGear Vault (with Shadowing) and msdeploy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box way to do this as the accepted modern model is to deploy everything on each deployment. I would also recommend this approach to classic asp, but not for your media/image files that should be versioned and delivered separately anyway.

You will need to write your own PowerShell script that identifies the changes...

You may want to lookup the last successful deployment to get the dates to compare to.